Divergence Issues in Series Expansion of Conformal Transformation of n-gon polygon with negative angle.
Greeting everyone.
I am having a numerical transformation of given polygon to the surface of an unit cirle (following the procedure by this article "A Conformal Mapping Method to Predict Low-Speed
Aerodynamic Characteristics of Arbitrary Slender Re-Entry Shapes by ROBERT S.SKULSKY"). The step following the used of Schwarz-Christoffel transformation of :
$$
z = D \int_{f_2}^{1} \left( \prod_{r=1}^{m} (\xi - \xi_{r})^{\alpha_r/\pi}\right) d\xi + K
$$
and its derivative
$$
\frac{dz}{d\xi} = \frac{1}{\xi^2} \prod_{r=1}^{m} (\xi - e^{i\theta_r})^{\alpha_r /\pi}
$$
where $\alpha_r$ is the angle between 2 line in vertex $r$ of the polygon satisfied the condition $\sum_{r=1}^{m}(a_r) = 2\pi$ across boundary. I understood that the mapping expression can be expanse using the Laurent series $$(\xi - e^{i\theta_r}) e^{\alpha_r /\pi} = \xi^{\alpha_r/\pi} \left(1 - \frac{e^{i\theta_r}}{\xi}\right)^{\alpha_r/\pi}$$
With the biomial series $\left(1 - \frac{e^{i\theta_r}}{\xi}\right)^{\alpha_r/\pi}$
result in
$$\left(1 - \frac{e^{i\theta_r}}{\zeta}\right)^{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}} = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{\pi}  \frac{e^{i\theta r}}{\zeta} + \frac{\alpha}{\pi} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi} - 1\right) \frac {e^{2i\theta r}}{2\zeta^2} - \frac{\alpha}{\pi} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi} - 1\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi} - 2\right) \frac {e^{3i\theta r}}{3\zeta^3} + \cdots$$
How ever the problem occur when the angle of the polygon having "concave" angle (negative $\alpha_r$) the numerical procedure divergence.
It was suggested that "rouding" the corner will help to smooth out the negative corner. However i really dont understand how to implement it into this series expansion. Any advice would be excellent. Thanks
